# Twitter4j Query by location + blacklistword

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

This question relates to the [twitter4j library](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Query.html)

So when doing a standard search in twitter, it's possible to do say @Apples near:UK

However when creating an object Query object:

```
Query q = new Query("@Apples near:UK");
```

doesn't work. Could someone explain how I would get the tweets from a specific location, say the UK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

If you [take a look at the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search-by-place) you'll see that you can use Place IDs rather than text searches.

For your particular case, you will need to geocode your search as per [the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search).

> The search operator “near” isn’t available in API, but there is a more precise way to restrict your query by a given location using the geocode parameter specified with the template “latitude,longitude,radius”, for example, “37.781157,-122.398720,1mi”.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I don't understand how to do this in twitter4j however

Comment: The documentation says that you can apply the Instance Method `geoCode` - see http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Query.html#geoCode-twitter4j.GeoLocation-double-java.lang.String-

Comment: Thanks! Yes I've seen this but would I have to create a polygon of the coordinates for the UK? Is that possible?

Comment: You need a point which is at the centre of the UK, and then a radius which encompasses the UK. You'll find many examples online.

Comment: Ok thanks for you help I'm going to have to work out another way to do this as that will mean a ton of inaccuracy

Comment: I managed to get this working eventually Terence!  Just thought I'd let you know ;)